# Unable to prevent user from going back to previous Log In page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Currently the users see login page when they open the application. Upon signing in, they get into the main page. I want to prevent the user from going back to the login page once they are logged in which the user can easily do by just clicking on the back button on the phone or the web browser.

The following method does that by preventing me from going back or forth to the page I want. For example if I identify the id as `#home`, it is going to prevent me from going back to homepage. Problem is this works for all my pages in my application less the one page I actually want to enforce this on which is my login page. When I use the login page's id, nothing happens and I am able to go back to the login page by clicking the back button. Please advise what I am doing wrong.

JS

```
// triggers when leaving any page
//this doesn't work cos I am using the id of my loginpage. Other page's ids works. 
$(document).on('pagebeforechange', function (e, data) {
    var to = data.toPage;

    if (typeof to === 'string') {
        var u = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(to);
        to = u.hash || '#' + u.pathname.substring(1);

        if (to === '#loginForm') { //will work if I use #benefits for example.
            alert('Can not transition the page!');
            $.mobile.changePage("#home", {
                transition: "flip"
            });

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            // remove active status on a button, if transition was triggered with a button
            $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active ui-shadow').css({
                'box-shadow': '0 0 0 #3388CC'
            });
        }
    }
});
```

HTML for LOG IN Page

```
<div data-role="page" id="loginForm" data-theme="e" data-add-back-btn="false">
            <header data-role="header">
                 <h1>Log In</h1> 
            </header>

            <form id="form1" name="form1" method="GET" action="http://example.com">
                <label for="id">Username   </label>
                <input type="text" name="id" id="id" />

                <label for="password">Password   </label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

                <input type="hidden" name="rank" id="rank" value="123">

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>    
            </form>
        </div>
```

HTML for Benefits Page

```
<div data-role="page" id="benefits" data-theme="e">
            <header data-role="header">
            <h1>Benefits</h1>   
        </header>
        <article data-role="content" >
            <div data-role="collapsible-set" id="benefitsList">
                <!--will fill up with info from database-->
            </div>
        </article>
        </div>
```

EDITED:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforechange', function (e, data) {
    var to = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage);
    if (typeof to === 'object') {
        var u = to.href;
        if (u === $.mobile.navigate.history.stack[0].url) {
            alert('You are logged in!');
            var current = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
            $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", current); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you use sessions? By checking is a user is logged in through sessions you can redirect them to the home page if they attempt to go to the login page manually

Comment: Ok to use any methods as long as I can prevent the 'Go Back'. Can you show me an example pls. Thank you.

Comment: what server side language are you using?

Comment: I am using PHP for the server side.

Comment: search for a login example online. you will find a lot of resources for your issue

Comment: Do you move to home page after successful login using ajax or you have ajax disabled?

Comment: @Omar ajax is enabled. I successfully move to homepage upon login.

Comment: And login page is the first page? "_duh_".

Comment: Yes login page is the first page. I don't get the 'duh'..

Comment: [duh](https://www.google.com/#q=define+duh) my question. I know the problem, when website is first initialised, first page has no hash in URL. Hash starts changing on next pages. I'll get you with a couple of solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that the code above works on all pages except for **first** page loaded, is because - by default - jQM doesn't change hash in URL for first page. The code above checks if there retrieves `hash` from URL, since there is no `hash` for first page, it returns `false` and thus doesn't prevent user from going back to "login page".

The code below checks URL and compares it with `.url` of first page loaded. The `.url` is stored in `$.mobile.navigate.history.stack` and it has `0` index, since it is first page.

#### jQuery Mobile 1.4

```
$(document).on('pagebeforechange', function (e, data) {
    var to = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(data.toPage);
    if (typeof to === 'object') {
        var u = to.href;
        if (u === $.mobile.navigate.history.stack[0].url) {
            alert('You are logged in!');
            var current = "#" + $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id;
            window.location.hash += current;
            return false; /* this will stop page change process */
        }
    }
});
```

---

#### jQuery Mobile <= 1.3

1. Change

   ```
   $.mobile.navigate.history.stack[0].url
   ```

   to

   ```
   $.mobile.urlHistory.stack[0].url
   ```
2. Change

   ```
   $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id
   ```

   to

   ```
   $.mobile.activePage[0].id
   ```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/d45j4/show/)** - **[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/d45j4/)**

Comment: Thanks for help. This code works - prevents me from going back to login page but it ends up preventing me from going back from other pages too. For example going back from 'benefits' page to 'home'.

Comment: At first I log in and go to home page. I select 'benefits' page from the homepage. After landing at 'benefits' page if I press 'back', it is fine and goes back to 'home.' From home, if I press back, the alert message appears. After this alert, when I go to 'benefits' page and try to go back to home, the alert appears too and doesn't allow me to go into homepage.

Comment: @keshk true, I just noticed it. It's because URL has been changed. You can use the following code instead if `return false`. `var current = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage"); $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", current);`. Meanwhile, I will think of better solution.

Comment: Hi I amended the codes as you mentioned and still has the same problem. Added the edited codes above for you to take a look in case I understood it wrongly.

Comment: @keshk your edit is correct. My code needs to be revised. I'm testing other solutions.

Comment: Tnks Omar. I tried the updated codes. It still has the same error where I am unable to go back to any previous page after I attempt to go back to log in page.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51602/discussion-between-omar-and-keshk)